# IRkernel::installspec() error when making kernel available to Jupyter on macOS Catalina

Tags: r, data-science, atom-editor

I am following the instructions on [this page](https://irkernel.github.io/installation/) to install IRkernel (with hopes of someday using the awesome [Hydrogen package](https://nteract.gitbooks.io/hydrogen/) in Atom) and ran across the following error:

I started by following the directions [here](https://nteract.io/kernels/r).

*In the terminal, I entered the following:*

```r
> install.packages(c('repr', 'IRdisplay', 
> 'evaluate', 'crayon', 'pbdZMQ', 
> 'devtools', 'uuid', 'digest'))
```

*These all install just fine because I saw the following:*

```r
The downloaded binary packages are in
/var/folders/fl/kv1bdvrx04524bnvdzhfx3p80000gn/T//RtmpwpXpvs/downloaded_packages
```

Next I installed the `IRkernel` package covered both [here](https://nteract.io/kernels/r) and [here](https://irkernel.github.io/installation/).

```r
devtools::install_github('IRkernel/IRkernel')
# ... this all installs fine...
* installing *source* package ‘IRkernel’ ...
** using staged installation
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
** testing if installed package can be loaded from final location
** testing if installed package keeps a record of temporary installation path
* DONE (IRkernel)
```

Then when I try to make the kernel visible to jupyter (step 2/2), I get the following error in the Terminal (running R).

```r
> IRkernel::installspec()
Error in IRkernel::installspec() :
jupyter-client has to be installed but “jupyter kernelspec --version” exited with code 127.
In addition: Warning message:
In system2("jupyter", c("kernelspec", "--version"), FALSE, FALSE) :
error in running command
```

My operating system information is below.

```r
> devtools::session_info()

─ Session info ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
setting  value
version  R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
os macOS Catalina 10.15.1
system x86_64, darwin15.6.0
ui X11
language (EN)
collate  en_US.UTF-8
ctype  en_US.UTF-8
tz America/Los_Angeles
date 2019-12-07



─ Packages ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
package * version date lib source
assertthat  0.2.1 2019-03-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
backports 1.1.5 2019-10-02 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
base64enc 0.1-3 2015-07-28 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
callr 3.3.2 2019-09-22 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
cli 1.1.0 2019-03-19 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
crayon  1.3.4 2017-09-16 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
curl  4.3 2019-12-02 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)
desc  1.2.0 2018-05-01 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
devtools  2.2.1 2019-09-24 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
digest  0.6.23  2019-11-23 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
ellipsis  0.3.0 2019-09-20 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
evaluate  0.14  2019-05-28 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
fs  1.3.1 2019-05-06 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
glue  1.3.1 2019-03-12 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
htmltools 0.4.0 2019-10-04 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
IRdisplay 0.7.0 2018-11-29 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
IRkernel  1.1 2019-12-08 [1] Github (IRkernel/IRkernel@a56a248)
jsonlite  1.6 2018-12-07 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
magrittr  1.5 2014-11-22 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
memoise 1.1.0 2017-04-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
pbdZMQ  0.3-3 2018-05-05 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
pillar  1.4.2 2019-06-29 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
pkgbuild  1.0.6 2019-10-09 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
pkgload 1.0.2 2018-10-29 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
prettyunits 1.0.2 2015-07-13 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
processx  3.4.1 2019-07-18 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
ps  1.3.0 2018-12-21 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
R6  2.4.1 2019-11-12 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
Rcpp  1.0.3 2019-11-08 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)
remotes 2.1.0 2019-06-24 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
repr  1.0.1 2019-05-14 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
rlang 0.4.2 2019-11-23 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
rprojroot 1.3-2 2018-01-03 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
sessioninfo 1.1.1 2018-11-05 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
testthat  2.3.1 2019-12-01 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.1)
usethis 1.5.1 2019-07-04 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
uuid  0.1-2 2015-07-28 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
withr 2.1.2 2018-03-15 [1] CRAN (R 3.6.0)
[1] /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library
```

Thank you in advance for your time!

Answer (score 1):

The error you get when running `IRkernel::installspec()` is most likely because jupyter is not in your PATH. The solution is:

1. Make sure you have jupyter installed and can execute it in a Unix shell (e.g. bash). On Mac OS you should be able to run this command in the Terminal app: `jupyter kernelspec --version`. In my case the result is: `5.3.4`.
2. If you can, then jupyter is in your `$PATH` and you should be able to invoke `R` from the terminal and run `IRkernel::installspec()`. Don't run it in the R app or R Studio, since they don't get your PATH from bash.
3. If you can't run jupyter in the Terminal app, then you have to add the directory where the executable is located to your `PATH` environment variable. On my system jupyter is in `~/anaconda3/bin/`, so adding that to my `PATH` will enable the shell to locate it: `export PATH="~/anaconda3/bin:$PATH"`. Now go back to step 1, and 2.